# Почему не происходит чтение из файла?

Tags: файлы, pascal, freepascal, turbopascal

Почему происходит некорректное чтение из файла? 0_o

> f.txt = 8 7 9 1 3 10 8 9 10

```
var a : integer; f : file of integer;
begin
  AssignFile(f, 'f.txt'); // Так же пробовал и просто Assign
  Reset(f);
  //Seek(f, 0);
  Read(f, a); // a = 540483640
end.
```

Comment: Ошибка есть? Какая?

Comment: @Эникейщик нет ошибок, только почему читается не 8, а 540483640

Comment: `540483640` оно не читается, это начальное неинициализированное значение переменной. сделаете в начале кода `a := -1`, будет оно выводится.

Comment: @teran ну а почему тогда не происходит чтение?

Comment: вы это значение то кстати где взяли? вывода у вас нет, или строки `write(a); readln;`  вы убрали из кода?

Comment: @teran это я в pascal ABC бряк поставил и смотрел значение, естественно когда уже выполнилась команда read

Comment: а до чтения значение такое же? :)

Comment: До чтения a = 0

Comment: А что читается, если изменить содержание f.txt?

Comment: @Эникейщик другое число, но такое же убогое ((

Comment: А у вас как компилируется?

Comment: напишите в f.txt просто 8. Что будет на выходе? Думаю, что проблема в том, что читается все сразу и потом преобразуется неведомым (мне) способом  в целое число.

Comment: @Эникейщик Теперь у меня выскакивает ошибка Program21.pas(7) : Ошибка времени выполнения: Чтение после конца потока невозможно.

Comment: @teran  Эникейщик  вы давно не писали на старом добром турбо паскале :) Ладно, пишу ответ :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov да уже лет 15 как :) но вообще меня мысль посещала про тип файла :) проверить только негде было :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В паскале (да и не только) данные в типизированном файле (в вашем случае - `file of integer`) хранятся в шестнадцатиричном виде.  В паскале integer занимал 2 байта, именно поэтому выскочила ошибка "Чтение после конца потока невозможно", ведь "8" - это один байт.

Если вы хотите читать целые числа из текстового файла, используйте TextFile (или Text в олдскульном варианте). Для freepascal, pascalABC.NET и Delphi это будет так:

```
var 
  a : integer; 
  f : TextFile;
begin
  AssignFile(f, 'f.txt');
  Reset(f);
  //Seek(f, 0);
  Read(f, a); // a = 8, хотя лучше читать сразу всю строку, используя несколько переменных

  <...>
 CloseFile(f);

end.
```

А в варианте для Turbo Pascal и самых первых версий Delphi - так:

```
var 
  a : integer; 
  f : Text;
begin
  Assign(f, 'f.txt');
  Reset(f);
  //Seek(f, 0);
  Read(f, a); { a = 8 поскольку в Turbo Pascal // не было комментарием :) }

  <...>
  Close(f);
end.
```